# Computing theta functions of lattices in practice

Tags: lattices, conformal-field-theory, theta-functions, vertex-algebras

I am motivated by a problem in 2d CFT to compute "generalized theta functions," expressions of the form
\begin{equation}
\vartheta_{L,u}(\tau) := \sum_{\alpha \in L} u(\alpha) q^{{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle}/2}\,,
\end{equation}
where $u:L\to \{\pm 1\}$ is some function I'll know explicitly. If it matters, $L$ will always be a sublattice of the $E_8$ lattice.

By "compute," I really mean present the RHS in terms of "nice" functions like $\theta_{1,2,3,4}$, but I'm open to alternatives (say Eisenstein series). One thing of moderate importance is the ability to look at q-expansions in, say, Mathematica. My hope is that lattice pros already have techniques to evaluate these sums and I am not re-inventing various wheels below.

I'm caustiously optimistic that if I can do this for regular theta functions (i.e. with $u(\alpha) = 1$), that I can do it with minus signs, as it will just flip some $\theta_{2,3}$s to $\theta_{1,4}$s.

## My Attempt: Calculating $\vartheta_{A_2}$

My trick thus far is to turn the calculation into sums over integers, then abuse integer shift-symmetry and re-write sums to remove "cross-terms." For example, for the $A_2$ lattice
\begin{align}
\sum_{\alpha\in A_2} q^{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle/2} 
&= \sum_{n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{Z}} q^{n_1^2-n_1n_2+n_2^2}\\
&=(\sum_{n_2 \textrm{ odd}}+\sum_{n_2 \textrm{ even}})\sum_{n_1}q^{n_1^2-n_1n_2+n_2^2}\\
&=\sum_{k}\sum_{n_1}q^{1 + 4 k + 4 k^2 - 2 k n_1  - n_1 + n_1^2}+\sum_{k}\sum_{n_1}q^{4 k^2 - 2 k n_1 + n_1^2}\\
&=\sum_{k}\sum_{n_1}q^{1 + 3 k + 3 k^2 + n_1 + n_1^2}+\sum_{k}\sum_{n_1}q^{3 k^2 + n_1^2}\\
&=\theta_2(6\tau)\theta_2(2\tau)+\theta_3(6\tau)\theta_3(2\tau)\,.
\end{align}
In going from the second to third line I've just written $n_2=2k+1$ and $n_2=2k$, and for third to fourth I've shifted $n_1 \mapsto n_1 + k + 1$ and $n_1 \mapsto n_1 + k$ for the respective sums.

### Problem 1: $\vartheta_{E_6}$ is a lot!

This approach gets involved very quickly. For a rank $N$ lattice, I have at least $N$ sums, and I don't always get to break each sum into 2. e.g. maybe I need to replace $n_i$ with $n_i = 3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$.

On page 127 of Conway & Sloane's book, they give $\theta_{E_6}$ in terms of $\theta_{2,3}$ as
\begin{equation}
\theta_{E_6}(\tau) = \frac{1}{4}f(\tau)^3+\theta_{A_2}(\tau)^3
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
f(\tau) = \theta_{A_2}\left(\frac{\tau}{3}\right)+\theta_{A_2}(\tau)
\end{equation}

**Question 1.A):** Can I obtain this answer without using that $A_2 \times E_6$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_3$ fixed sublattice of $E_8$?

I imagine a technique where I present the inner product $\langle \alpha,\alpha\rangle/2$ as coming from an upper triangular matrix. i.e. write $\alpha$ as an integer sum over simple roots $\alpha = \sum_{i} n_i \alpha_i$ then
\begin{equation}
\langle \alpha,\alpha\rangle/2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}n_1\\ n_2\\ \vdots \\ n_N \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & c_{12} & \dots  & c_{1N} \\
      & 1      & \dots  & c_{2N} \\
      &        & \ddots & \vdots \\
      &        &        & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}n_1\\ n_2\\ \vdots \\ n_N \end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{equation}
My hope is that shift-symmetry and breaking up sums have natural actions in some linear algebra approach like this.

**Question 1.B):** Does such a technique exist already, or is there a quicker way to do these computations?

### Problem 2: Recognizing Theta-Functions

When I extend this procedure and try it on the next-simplest lattice, $A_3$, I don't obtain an answer which is obviously products of theta functions like I did for $A_2$. In particular, I can make my sums decouple, but I get arbitrary "blocks" of the form
\begin{align}
\mathbb{B}_{A,B,C} 
&:=\sum_{k} q^{\frac{1}{2}(A k^2 + B k + C)}\\
&= q^{\frac{C}{2}}\vartheta\left(\frac{B\tau}{2},A\tau\right)\\
&= q^{\frac{C}{2}}(q^A;q^A)_\infty\theta\left(-q^{(A+B)/2},q^A\right)
\end{align}
where $\vartheta(z,\tau)$ is the regular Jacobi-theta function $\theta(w,q)$ is the [q-theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-theta_function) with $w=e^{i\pi z}$. For special $\{A,B,C\}$ the relationships to $\theta_{1,2,3,4}$ are clear. And maybe that's the best I can do unless I can find some identities relating an arbitrary $\mathbb{B}_{A,B,C}$ to $\theta_{1,2,3,4}$, or other similarly "nice" functions.

**Question 2:** Are there better expressions for my "blocks"?